Select multiple calendars
In the Outlook app you can select multiple calendars.
How to do it programmatically through C# VSTO outlook?
I set the NavigationFolder.isSelected property for several calendars as true, but all these calendars remain unselected.
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.CalendarModule calendarModule = (Outlook.CalendarModule)mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar);
Outlook.NavigationGroups groups = calendarModule.NavigationGroups;
Outlook.NavigationGroup calendar = null;
foreach (Outlook.NavigationGroup group in groups)
{
    if (navGroup.Name == "MyCalendar")
        calendar = group;
}
foreach (Outlook.NavigationFolder folder in calendar.NavigationFolders)
{
    folder.IsSelected = true;
}

